# should my static class be derived from UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour instead?

Tags: unity, c#

I am working on creating an object to maintain state of the game, player data, etc.  It is static (singleton lifecyle) through the life of my game.

I started down the path of a static class, with a static instance, like this:

```
public class PlayerState
{
    private static PlayerState DATA_INSTANCE = new PlayerState();
    public static PlayerState Instance
    {
        get { return DATA_INSTANCE;  }
    }
}
```

Then I started looking around and I see implementations that derive from `UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour` and implement the instance handling differently, adding the script to a game object and using `DontDestroyOnLoad()` to ensure it stays in memory.

So I am wondering: what is the correct idiomatic pattern in unity for a singleton type?

Do I really need all of the unity functionality of a `UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour` derived type (eg: `Update()`) for my static type?

I admit I am uneasy about static classes, in general.  In this case, I am equally uneasy adding another type that potentially gets in the frame cycle when its not needed (I mean that unity will call the methods like  `Update()` for every cycle).

Thnx
Matt

Comment: [We have an existing question "In Unity, how do I correctly implement the Singleton Pattern"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/116009/39518), though my personal position, [similar to that expressed in Game Programming Patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/singleton.html), is that there isn't one correct implementation of singletons. You consider your requirements, and you pick the implementation that serves those needs. For instance, if you want to be able to inspect the singleton's state in the inspector, a MonoBehaviour might be useful. If not, then don't.

Comment: But if you're worried about message functions getting called when you don't need them, that's not a concern: in Unity, if you don't implement the Update method, the engine takes no time trying to call it.

Comment: Yes I saw the first post earlier.  I think your second comment, @DMGregory, is really the answer I was looking for.  :)

Comment: @tatmanblue If you want to get started with architecture - http://www.gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html . If you are looking for a `StateManager` you might want to take a look at this question. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/167611/how-to-implement-a-very-simple-game-state-manager-in-unity/167811#167811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every class in a Unity project must necessarily inherit from `MonoBehaviour`. If there is no good reason to attach an instance of your class to a specific GameObject and you don't have a reason why you would need it to implement any Unity event, then there is no reason why you need to make it one.

In fact putting the whole game state into a `static` class (implementing the singleton pattern or not) is [my favorite way to share data between scenes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110958/unity-5-what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-data-between-scenes).

Comment: Note also that static classes *can't* inherit from *any* parent class. Attempting to do so will throw a `Static class 'X' cannot derive from type 'Y'. Static classes must derive from object` compiler error.